# Why isn't my score recording on the playerprefs is there GetFloat method?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Why isn't my score recording on the playerprefs ? is there GetFloat method? Can anyone help me to post the least score of my game it just like the most least seconds will get the best time record ever

```
var myTimer: float = 0;
var GUITimer: GUIText;
    function Start() {
}

function Update() {
    GUITimer.text = "Time: " + myTimer;
    if (myTimer > -1) {
        myTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider) {
    if (other.tag == "FinishLine") {
        SaveTime();
    }
}

function OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label(Rect(10, 10, 500, 200), myTimer.ToString());
}

function SaveTime() {
    if (myTimer < PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JeepneyScore3")) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("JeepneyScore3", myTimer);
    }
    Application.LoadLevel("Levels");
}
```

Comment: For which platform are you developing?

Comment: The code looks fine. Two things: (1) This won't solve your problem, but getFloat/setFloat exist; (2) Try to put some debug messages and see what step is giving you problems. Maybe the collision is not detected, and the PlayerPrefs value's not updated as a consequence.

Comment: unity sir . this is my timer

Comment: Android? iOS? Desktop?  I ask because there are some platform dependent issues with PlayerPrefs.  Try adding "PlayerPrefs.Save()" after you call "PlayerPrefs.SetInt(...,...). Edit.  Also, change SetInt/GetInt to SetFloat/GetFloat

Comment: Is your project 2d or 3d? If 2d you need OnTriggerEnter2D in javascript as well I assume

Comment: 3d sir .. Do you have some ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I see three problems:

First, you're tracking a float, but calling [`GetInt()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html) and [`SetInt()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html). Keep your data types consistent. You should either round/floor/etc, or call [`GetFloat()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetFloat.html) and [`SetFloat()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetFloat.html).

Second, you're not calling [`Save()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html), which means your changes will never write to disk. You might consider something like this:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("JeepneyScore3", myTimer);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Third, you're not handling the case where no data exists. You could check for existing data with [`HasKey()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html), but in this case it's simpler to rely on the second form of `GetFloat()`. The default form, which you're calling, returns zero if the requested key isn't set:

```
//returns value of "foo", or zero if no such value
var prevBest = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("foo");
```

If you're looking for a time below the player's previous best, but the default "best" is already `0.0`, you're going to have a hard time beating that time.

You can instead provide your own default value:

```
//returns value of "foo", or ten thousand if no such value
var prevBest = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("foo", 10000.0);
```

Finally, you should make sure that `SaveTime()` is actually being called at the appropriate time. You could add a simple debug line, like this:

```
Debug.Log("SaveTime was called");
```

And then make sure that's showing up. If not, you need to fix your collision check.

Comment: is the foo is the Mytimer?

Comment: "foo" would be whatever PlayerPrefs key you're working with. You mentioned "JeepneyScore3" in your question.

Comment: Just curious why would you call playerprefs.save() shouldnt it do that automatically when you SET the variable?

Comment: @crychair Unless Unity changed the behavior, PlayerPrefs will wait for an explicit save call. Saving is a fairly expensive operation (more so if you call it a lot and/or have a lot of data to write), so some people would rather wait until a level load.

Comment: @rutter see I just usually create an object that doesnt delete on load or w.e. that function is. And then set the playerpref and atach the script to the object. This way yo dont even have to save, but saving is probably better when dealing with multiple scenes, this was just a two sceen mini game. Thanks for the knowledge.